vercel deploy success but access web error Nextjs 14 undici wrong verssion

Deploy success but access web Application error: a server-side exception has occurred
enviroments NEXT_PUBLIC in vercel, node 20.x
un build success on local and vercel. But on vercel access page after deploy fetch failed.
Does anyone have the solution. Help me

Have you added to all the env vars under Project Settings in Vercel?
